# Why some phrases auto recognised as tags and other not

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, tags, search

In Stackoverflow when I search for `angular` it show me the tag [angular] and so I can follow it and when I search for `vue` or `react` it isn't.

**Angular search:**
[image: angular search]

**Vue search:**
[image: vue search]

When I search for `[vue]` it is working and show the Vue tag and let me follow it.

Comment: There are no tags called vue or react, they are synonyms for vue.js and reactjs. Type in reactjs and it's auto-recognised perhaps the . in vue.js confuses things.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is addressed in [this blog entry](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/29/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/): only searches corresponding to the top 40 tags are auto-recognized as tag searches,. Per our [policy](/a/47635) (see also the last section of [this](/a/10844)), this should be closed as a duplicate, but since it's not possible to close as a duplicate of a blog entry, I have to specify it as "off-topic".

Comment: The issue that  I noticed is that if you search for `[vue]` or `[react] it will change automatically to `[vue.js]` or `[reactjs]`, it causes me to think that you cant follow React and Vue, therefore I asked this question

Comment: OdedBD, While it's a pain ... you can use the search term: `"vue" -[vue.js] -[vuejs2]` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22vue%22+-%5Bvue.js%5D+-%5Bvuejs2%5D&mixed=1) - after you cut away the chaff you are left with a search for *just* the word "**vue**".

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog that is not a close reason. Since when do we declare a question off-topic because it is answered in the blog? At best it is a duplicate of a blog post but AFAIK we can't dupe vote yet against a blog post. If you have no other dupe target then that comment of yours should be promoted to an answer.

Comment: Answer given by Jeff 10 years ago: "The top (n) tags in the tag list are automatically turned into tags when they appear in searches", this hasn't been changed to this day.

Comment: I've no clue why folks think its ok to close against the blog. That's never been how we have done things. While the blog can be a canonical reference, there's a good reason why we can't close against the blog - its still an external, and mutable resource, even if owned by SO. Also kinda hard to search without google :D

Comment: Shadow fixed it up: it's now closed as the proper duplicate. I do apologize for the mistaken off-topic closure.

Comment: My comment was when I was still under the impression we had no proper dupe target on meta yet, just one on the blog. You found a better target around the same time, so it's moot now.